# Why isn't java used that much in artificial intelligence

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

Are there any reasons why java isn't used that much in AI besides polarization based upon what the prominent researchers are using? It seems that most cs students, at least in so, cal, know java so it would seem that it would be more prominent.

Comment: Vote to close: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: so what in your opinion is the most used language in the AI related tasks?

Comment: PROLOG,LISP and AIML(beginning to find it's way into AI) and many more. You can't question why this and why not Java. It's like why is an apple like apple,not an orange?

Comment: I respectfully disagree. We don't use verilog to write mobile applications. We don't use assembly, for the most part, to do business applications. We generally don't use java to program microcontrollers. We use a language for its benefits or because it's all we know.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This community seems to be heading down a crappy road. Some of the best questions on this website and one of the major reasons I visited the site so much because of the questions that solicited a debate. Granted this question isn't anywhere near the best of questions but it seems the people here are

Comment: shooting down questions that don't match the rules(just because they don't match the rules), it's almost robotic. Notice this question made it to 2 upvotes before it was voted to close. Lastly if you limit this site to questions that don't solicit debate you end up with an irrelevant site as many many blogs cover the daily questions that don't get voted to close.

Comment: Is there any evidence to support the assumption that it isn't used? Maybe if your definition of AI is very narrow this might be true.

Comment: @trutheality Oh there are plenty of examples of it being used but just not anywhere near as plentiful as other languages.

Comment: Again, no evidence. People *teach* logic programs with PROLOG (hey that's what it's for), and self-modifying code with LISP (also what it's for). Python has some convenient NLP packages (and it's easy to use). Matlab is easy for anything with Matrix manipulation, R is easy for statistics, but when you are writing a program for speed and efficiency, the go-to languages are still C++ and Java. I do my AI research in Java, a few others in our department do too. I don't think that there is any language that is dominant in our circle, everyone uses a bit of everything.

Comment: @user1394187: The point of this site is precisely *not* to be just another programming forum.  In the early days, debate-style question occurred, but it was soon realised that they decreased the signal-to-noise ratio of the site.  I suggest reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah, now it's just some kind of professional pseudoblog in the best of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion is kind of subjective...but....artificial intelligence is computer science.  Computer science is language agnostic.  The point of AI is AI, not programming languages.

That said, from what I remember, certain languages have features that make implementing **certain** AI algorithms much easier.  So sometimes it might make sense to use a specific language if its going to make your life easier.  Im guessing that's the case here.